# Java:memory allocation,stack vs heap

Tags: java

Please could you give me a correct divide to members stored in the stack and others stored in the heap when we instantiate the class below:

```
class A{

    int x;
    static int y;

    void meth1(){
        //some code
    }

    static void meth2(){
        //some code
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Java pre-8:

- `static` fields are being allocated in `PermGen` - `static int y` goes there;
- `.class` objects are being allocated in `PermGen` - `class A` goes there;
- Primitives such as `int`, `long`, `double` etc, declared within `void` or function are allocated in stack and not a subject for garbage collection - they're destroyed together with return address and arguments;
- Other local and member variables are being allocated in the heap - `int x` goes there;

Regarding stack - it is used to store instruction pointer value to the command invoked subroutine, and all arguments passed. I'll write an example:

```
public void a(int x) {
}

public void b() {
    this.a(5);
}
```

When `this.a(5)` is being invoked, `5` goes to stack together with the address of line of code (assembler code, not Java) where `this.a` was invoked.

In Java 8, `PermGen` was replaced with `metaspace`, so `static` fields and `.class` objects are now there. Regarding member variables and stack, nothing changed.

Comment: Fixed unprecise statement about heap allocation.